# Scala: higher-kinded types, type projections and type mismatch error

Tags: scala, type-systems, higher-kinded-types, type-projection

I have the following code:

```
trait M[Type[_]]{
  type T[X] = Type[X]
  def from[A](f: T[A]): A
}
class ListM extends M[List]{ def from[A](f: T[A]) = f.head }

class Trans[A, X[_], B <: M[X]](val r: X[Option[A]])
trait CurriedTrans[X[_], B <: M[X]]{ type Type[A] = Trans[A, X, B] }
class TransM[X[_], B <: M[X]](val b: B) extends M[CurriedTrans[X, B]#Type]{
  def from[A] = (f: T[A]) => b.from(f.r).get
}
```

and I can instantiate variables of type TransM in two ways:

```
val x1 = new TransM[List, ListM](new ListM)
val x2 = new TransM[ListM#T, ListM](new ListM)
```

I think ListM#T is redundant type parameter, so I'm trying to eliminate it:

```
trait M{
  type T[X]
  def from[A](f: T[A]): A
}
class ListM extends M {
  type T[X] = List[X]
  def from[A](f: T[A]) = f.head
}

class Trans[A, B <: M](val r: B#T[Option[A]])
class TransM[B <: M](val b: B) extends M {
  type T[X] = Trans[X, B]
  def from[Y] = (f: T[Y]) => b.from(f.r).get
}
```

to instantiate variable as

```
val x = new TransM[ListM](new ListM)
```

Unfortunately, the second implementation can't be compiled because of a type mismatch error:

```
type mismatch;
 found   : f.r.type (with underlying type B#T[Option[Y]])
 required: TransM.this.b.T[?]
      def from[Y] = (f: T[Y]) => b.from(f.r).get
                                          ^
```

Can I fix this issue and simplify my code or should I write boilerplate ListM#T everywhere?

Comment: The first block of code doesn't compile, method `from` in `TransM` is defined with the wrong signature.

Comment: Why do you need the specific type of `B <: M[X]` for `TransM`? Wouldn't `M[X]` suffice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ziggystar says it: Drop the bound `B` and use `M[X]` directly:

```
class TransM[X[_]](val b: M[X]) extends M[CurriedTrans[X, M[X]]#Type] {
  def from[A](f: T[A]) = b.from(f.r).get
}

val x1 = new TransM(new ListM)
```

You could consider to do the same for `Trans` and `CurriedTrans`. If you need the inner type of `M`, you can always expose it through a type member of `Trans` and `CurriedTrans`.